# Detailed java thread state in eclipse debugger?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, debugging, concurrency

Is it possible to see detailed JVM thread state in eclipse debugger? For example, which monitors thread has, which ones it waits for etc?

This would help to debug concurrent hangs.

Comment: have you read through any documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported by the Eclipse Debugger nativly, what you want is a Profiler

- [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
- [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/)

and many more. You can then start the debugging in Eclipse and connect the profiler program remotely to your running JVM instance. VisualVM also offers an [Eclipse launcher](http://visualvm.java.net/eclipse-launcher.html).

YourKit has different features regarding concurrency, for instance [Monitor profiling](http://www.yourkit.com/features/index.jsp#monitor_profiling). There you will get detailed information about the threads and their interaction.

[image]